# searching in 2d loop

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

why do i always get the output incorrect! even if enter the matching id
its a string 2d array

```
public void getWorkId(){
int i = 0;
do{
    //taking id
System.out.println("id: ");
workId= input.next();
//searching for matching id
for(int row = 0; row < mangerTable.length; row++){
        if(mangerTable[row][1].equals(workId)){
            //there is a match
            i=1;
            break;
        }else{
            //there isn't match
            System.out.println("incorrect!");
            i= -1;
            break;
        }//end else
    }//end row loop
}while(i>0);

}
```

Comment: you're using a nested loop but you  are never using i for anything. Most likely a typo on mangerTable[row][1]. Also please read the guidlines for questions

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the ID for each manager is the **second** element in each row as you've indicated in your code (`if(mangerTable[row][1].equals(workId)){`) so, with that in mind and with so little information, I think what you are trying to do is something like this (read comments in code):

```
// searching for matching id
int i = -1;
do {
    String id = "";
    while (id.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.print("Enter ID to Find (q to quit): -> ");
        id = input.nextLine();
        // Quit?
        if (id.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
            return;
        }
        /* Validate input. Assuming all ID's are numerical:
           Are all characters supplied numerical digits? */ 
        if (!id.matches("\\d+")) {
            System.out.println("Invalid ID! (" + id + ") Try again..."
                             + System.lineSeparator());
            id = ""; // Empty id to ensure re-loop.
        }
    }

    for (int row = 0; row < mangerTable.length; row++) {
        if (mangerTable[row][1].equals(id)) {
            //there is a match
            i = row;
            break; // Found...no need to carry on.
        }
    }
    if (i >= 0) {
        //there is a match
        System.out.println("Match Found In Row Index: " + i 
                + "  (literal Row #" + (i + 1) + ")");
        System.out.println("Contents of Row:  " + Arrays.toString(mangerTable[i]));
        String yn = "";
        while (yn.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.print("Want to Find another ID? (y/n): ");
            yn = input.nextLine();
            /* Validate input:
               Is either the `y` or `n` supplied (in any letter case)? 
               `(?i)` makes the expression letter case insensitive. */
            if (!yn.matches("(?i)[yn]")) {
                System.out.println("Invalid choice (" + yn + ")! Try Again..."
                        + System.lineSeparator());
                yn = "";  // Empty yn to ensure re-loop.
            }
        }
        if (yn.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
            System.out.println();
            i = -1;  // -1 to i to ensure do/while re-loop.
        }
    }
    else {
        //there isn't match
        System.out.println("No ID Match Found!" + System.lineSeparator());
    }
} while (i < 0);
```